# Weird return value of C++20 requires expression

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, requires-expression

Consider the *requires expression*:

```
constexpr auto b = requires { []{}; };
```

GCC [pass](https://godbolt.org/z/eooMEK) the following two `static_assert`:

```
 static_assert(b);
 static_assert(!b);
```

This looks extremely weird. I expect that the value of `b` should be `true`. Is this just a GCC Bug?

Comment: Definitely seems like a bug of some sort. It gets weirder if we explicitly declare `b` as a bool https://godbolt.org/z/1ebTP6

Comment: Unless the code is ill-formed NDR, I would say gcc bug, clang/msvc reject it [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fqxn1o).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica. Ok then I report it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99546).

Comment: @Jarod42. This code is well-formed. Clang has not implemernt the [P0315R4](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambdas_in_unevaluated_contexts) and this is a MSVC Bug.

Comment: fwiw, different incarnation of weirdness: https://godbolt.org/z/bbKTnh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't Schrödinger's Requirement: `b` should clearly be either `true` or `false`.

The requirement here:

```cpp
constexpr auto b = requires { []{}; };
```

is a *simple-requirement*. We're just checking that if the *expression* `[]{}` is a valid expression. And... it is! So `b` should just be true. This is a gcc bug (and doubly so with [StoryTeller's example](https://godbolt.org/z/1ebTP6) demonstrating that in a slighly different spelling `b` doesn't even count as a constant expression).

Comment: I really like the Schrödinger part.